# editable Div border styles

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have editable area to editable my content. The border of the div should be like the below image. Kindly  reply me whether it can achieved  with Css or any other method using script or whatsoever. Since I have rights to up image. I try to represent it as below.
Replace hashtag with circle and dots with line

#..............................#..............................#
 .                                                             .
 .                                                             .
 .                                                             .
 #                                                             #
 .                                                             .
 .                                                             .
 .                                                             .
 #..............................#..............................#

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, you mean this:

o________________o_______________o _ _ _ _ oo _ _ _ _o_______________o_______________o

or should the circle be in the middle of the line?

For this solution above, i recommend to add in the css:

```
.box-with-border {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

and add through javascript some divs around:

`$('.box-with-border').after('<div class="circle"></div>');`

css:

```
.circle {
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #000000;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

Comment: Well Thank u every one ...  I got this code .. It good                                                             border: 15px solid transparent;
border-image: url('box.png');
border-image-slice: 13;

Answer (score 0):

Maybe *Border Image* ist what you are looking for.

```
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0px 0px 25px;
border-image: url(http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/border.png) 0 0 25 repeat;
```

As name implies, you can use images, in contrast to longer existing css-border.
See [css tricks: understanding border image](http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/) for coding information.
There is also a [border image generator](http://border-image.com/#%7B%22src%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FTR%2Fcss3-background%2Fborder.png%22%2C%22linkBorder%22%3Atrue%2C%22borderWidth%22%3A%5B0%2C0%2C0%2C0%5D%2C%22imageOffset%22%3A%5B0%2C0%2C25%2C0%5D%2C%22fill%22%3Afalse%2C%22setRepat%22%3Afalse%2C%22repeat%22%3A%5B%22repeat%22%2C%22repeat%22%5D%2C%22scaleFactor%22%3A3%2C%22setRepeat%22%3Atrue%7D) and in the link points to settings like you may want to achive.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible with the default border properties. This is how ever possible with some creative code. You would need to place the content in a div surround it with div's and use the surrounding divs as the top, bottom and side borders. Then with styling and code you could dynamically change the pattern and the style of the borders as you wish.